# Get control of main page in showModalDialog?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my main page i have a label and a button ..on button click i want to open a new popup window using  showModalDialog ..In my popup window i have a textbox and a close button  ..i want to put something in textbox and click the button . popup need to be close ..Textbox value should show in main page lebel .....

My Main page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ModalPopupValuePass._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function Abc()
       {
       debugger;
         //window.showModalDialog("FIRE/Popup.aspx",null,"resizable: yes");
         var style = 'dialogWidth:350px;dialogHeight:100px;dialogleft:200px;dialogtop:200px;status:no;help:no;';
         var respond = window.showModalDialog("FIRE/Popup.aspx", this, '', style);
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Abc();"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In cs page of main page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = hf1.Value;
        }
```

My popup page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Popup.aspx.cs" Inherits="ModalPopupValuePass.FIRE.Popup" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function Def()
       {
       debugger;
       window.opener.document.getElementById('<%=hf1.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
         window.close();
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="Def();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But i am not getting the mainpage control in popup ...need help..!!

Comment: Webpages, as opposed to WinForms, don't really have any relation to or knowledge of each other (there's no 'owner' or 'parent' page). So it can't resolve that hf1 in the popup. You could either try hard-coding the complete ID (not sure if the browsers will allow access to the element anyway) of another approach is to only use one page. Have the 'popup' just be a div and use some CSS and javascript to get a light-box type 'modal' effect.

Comment: @Mark can you please give an example ..small one if possible

Comment: You may want to look up the .Net Ajax toolkit modal popup extender that allows asp:panel controls to be used like a model pop up

Comment: @jgok222 thanks for your reply but i have a constraint of using showModalDialog..

Comment: If you are getting popup new page then how come you can find that control in new page ,the most possible thing you can do it that ,you can play with query string and try to send your data with query string.